# logging into website using php

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, web-crawler

Im trying to auto login into a website using php, i dont get any error with this code neither it gives any result to me. here is the code i tried, i get only a blank page, im expecting the sourcecode of the page after login.

```
<?php
$fields_string=array();
$url = 'https://subscriber.hoovers.com/H/login/login.html';

$fields = array(
        "j_username"=>"XXXXXX",
"j_password"=>"XXXX"
    );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) 
{ 
$fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; 
 }
 rtrim($fields_string,'&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: Do you have access to the code of the login page? Are you displaying errors?

Comment: Have you tried setting `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` in case the login is doing a redirect (which isn't unheard of)?

Comment: @james yes i have the id and pasword which are working

Comment: @cillosis im new to php unaware of CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION could you please be more clear on this how to use!

Comment: @SantoshKumar The manual says this, *TRUE to follow any "Location: " header that the server sends as part of the HTTP header (note this is recursive, PHP will follow as many "Location: " headers that it is sent, unless CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS is set).* http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: @cillosis i tried to use curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); after  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url); but no change in out, am i doing correct?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get your script to return the sourcecode of the page by adding these curl options:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

By default curl doesn't trust the web server’s certificate, the last option above tells curl not to verify the web server. You might want to switch that last option to this:

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "path/to/your/cacert.pem");
```

If you are going to go this route, I would check out [Using cURL in PHP to access HTTPS (SSL/TLS) protected sites](http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/) its a great tutorial and will go over everything you need to know about it.